# Purpose of const argument other than avoiding mistake

Tags: c, keil, c51

I'm programming 8051 microcontroller using keil C51 C compiler, which only support C90.

I want to send a byte of data via UART, the function look like this:

```
void Uart_send(char data){
   //...
}
```

Use 1:

```
char a = 123;
Uart_send(a); //work great
```

Use 2:

```
Uart_send(123);//doesn't work, but no error or warning from compiler
```

In the latter case, 1 byte is sent, but not the correct value (123).

If I change my code to:

```
void Uart_send(const char data){
   //...
}
```

Then everything works perfectly.

From my understanding and several sources on the internet, the only purpose of "const" is to prevent the function from changing its argument (in other words, to prevent the programmer from changing argument by mistake). Then why does my second method not work?

Edit: This is my full code:

UART.h

```
typedef struct {
    char Buffer[10];
    char *p;
    char Ready;
    void (*Load)(char Data);
    void (*Transmit)();
    void (*Flush)();
} _uart;
extern _uart UART;
```

UART.c

```
#include "UART.h"
#include <reg51.h>

#define EOF 0x00
/*
0000_0000: EOF
0000_0001: countdown
1xxx_xxxx: primary time set
1xxx_xxxx: secondary time set
0111_xxxx: set phase

*/
#define Wait() for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
void Load(const char Data){
    *UART.p = Data;
    if(Data == EOF){
        UART.Ready = 1;
    }
    ++UART.p;
}
void Transmit(){
    int i;
    char *p;
    p = UART.Buffer;
    while(1){
        SBUF = *p;
        while(~TI);
        TI = 0;
        Wait();//make sure slave finish process data before sending next byte
        if(*p == EOF) break;//we are done
        ++p;
    }
    UART.Flush();
}
void Flush(){
    UART.p = UART.Buffer;
    UART.Ready = 0;
}
_uart UART = {
    {EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF, EOF},
    UART.Buffer, 0,
    Load,
    Transmit,
    Flush
};
```

main.c

```
#include "UART.h"
//.....
UART.Load(123);
UART.Load(0x00); //0x00 = EOF
UART.Transmit();
```

Comment: `Uart_send(123)` shouldn't be a problem. Can you please elaborate on the "doesn't work" part? What value *is* being "sent"?

Comment: Do you have a prototype for `Uart_send()` in scope?

Comment: How is `Uart_send` declared? I assume you include a header to call it, how is it declared there?

Comment: Not in C, @Blaze. `const` qualified objects are not really "constant".

Comment: AFAICT Your code should behave exactly the same in any C compiler. Are your actual code referring to a const pointer perhaps?

Comment: So that's just a C++ thing, then? I didn't know that. And another valuable thing learned today. Thanks! :)

Comment: As for the "purpose" of `const` arguments, beside what's mentioned it's also tells the caller *intent* of the function, and makes code easier to understand and use and maintain.

Comment: In retrospect, I think `const` should have been named `"readonly"` (quotes included to mark as inexistent).

Comment: @Blaze For `case` only compile-time constants can be used. A `const` argument can't be a compile-time constant in C++ either.

Comment: @pmg - Or perhaps it should have been made a full-measure and produced integral constant expressions, like it in C++.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see. Thanks.

Comment: @StoryTeller: that would work too :)

Comment: In the code you have shown, there is a difference between the `Load` function pointer in the `_uart` `struct`, and actual function `Load`

Comment: @sp2danny I made a mistake there. However this code work perfectly

Comment: Your "full code" is really not related to the initial code and the problems it might have. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "8051 microcontroller using keil C51" Why not use something from the current millennium instead? Those old Keil compilers were almost as horrible as the 8051 core. Luckily, better tools arrived in the 1990s.

Answer (score 5):

Now when we can see your code the problem is clear: You don't have a function declaration (a *prototype*) in the header file.

In C you really need to declare things before you can use them, otherwise the compiler will not know about them.

Note that there's a big difference between standard editions here. In older C standards (before C99) using a function would implicitly declare by deducing the argument types from the call (which in your case would have been wrong since `123` is an `int`). From C99 and onward that's not really allowed anymore.

Comment: there seem to be a prototype?

Answer (score 2):

> Purpose of const argument other than avoiding mistake

Compiler can do some optimizations with the `const` present.